# Отслеживание звука Windows 10 на Python

Tags: python, аудио, уведомления

Всем привет. Кто-то знает, можно ли каким-то образом на Python реагировать на звук, который создаёт компьютер? Например, звуковые уведомления, музыка и т. д.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Гайд:
https://g.zeos.in/?q=change%20system%20volume%20in%20python

Такой вопрос уже есть:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828752/python-change-master-application-volume